# Conditional for autosave or auto draft?

Tags: hooks, save-post

I am attempting to create a file using `fopen()` on `save_post`. I am having trouble finding the right condtionals to prevent the the file from being created from an auto save. I only want to create the file when I click publish the post. Currently the file is created when I click "add new" and when I fill in the title.

I have tried several combinations using `wp_is_post_revision()` and `wp_is_post_autosave()` any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What action are you using to hook your code?  If it's the `save_post` action; you can use something like `if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;`.  This will prevent the function from firing (past the code above) if it is an auto-save.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action hook; then you can prevent the code from executing during an autosave with the following conditional:

```
function do_not_autosave( $post ) {

    // Check to see if we are autosaving
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    // Rest of the code here
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'do_not_autosave');
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets be half way there. It now does not auto save when adding a title but it does create a file when I click add new. It creates the file auto-draft. Any idea how to stop the initial auto save?

Comment: Can you please go back and edit your original question; and include the code you are using?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-save_post-called-twice/).

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old answer, you should check the post status, when you create a post (before starting editing), it has post status **auto-draft**.

So the code should be:

```
function my_theme_name_save_post_callback($post_id, $post) {    
    if ( !wp_is_post_autosave( $post ) && $post->post_status !== 'auto-draft' && 
         !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

       /* your code here */

    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_theme_name_save_post_callback', 10, 3);
```

Replace "my_theme_name" prefix with your theme name (slug), as a best practice.
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/best-practices/#prefix-everything